# Python: printing ranges for each row

Tags: python, range

I have a table containing a street name along with it's first and last house number.  What I want to do is to print out the range for each street name so I end up with something like this:

```
1 The Street
2 The Street
3 The Street
1 Main Street
2 Main Street
etc.
```

I am new to Python and this is what I have got so far:

```
>>> import csv
>>> inp = csv.reader(open("/tmp/HSN.csv", "r"), delimiter = ',')
>>> a = (line[0]) #street name column
>>> b = int(line[1]) #first house number column
>>> c = int(line[2]) #last house number column
>>> for d in range(b, c+1):
         print a, d
         continue
```

Unfortunately this only seems to do the range for the last entry in the CSV file.  Has anyone got any ideas how to print out all of the numbers within that range, while also printing out the street name for each number in that range?

Comment: I'm not too sure I understand what #first house number column and #last house number column really mean. Could you showcase some an example?

Comment: please post your input file format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where do you define line? It is probably left over from previous testing. Your logic is fine, you just want to do it for each row. Try this:

```
import csv
inp = csv.reader(open("/tmp/HSN.csv", "r"), delimiter = ',')
for line in inp:
    a = (line[0]) #street name column
    b = int(line[1]) #first house number column
    c = int(line[2]) #last house number column
    for d in range(b, c+1):
        print a, d
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly.  Looks like I was nearly correct apart from missing the code for defining line.

Answer (score 1):

Is your example missing code? Where does `line` variable come from?

The following code should get you started:

```
inp = csv.reader(open("/tmp/HSN.csv", "r"), delimiter = ',')
for line in input:
  street_name = line[0]
  first_house_num = int(line[1])
  last_house_num = int(line[2])
  for house_num in range(first_house_num, last_house_num + 1):
    print('{} {}'.format(house_num, street_name)
```

1. loop through every street in your file
2. get every streets' name and range
3. loop through the streets range and print each number on a seperate line